# Merging All Columns of Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have many pandas DataFrames for stocks. They all have the form:

```
df_asset = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random((5,4)), index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])
```

I have stored the asset names and their DataFrames in the dictionary:

```
stock_data = {'AAPL' : df_AAPL, 'CSCO' : df_CSCO ...}
```

I want to join all of these DataFrames to create a MultiIndexed DataFrame of the form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random((15,4)), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list(range(1,6)), ['AAPL', 'CSCO', 'AMZN']]), columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])
```

What is the most elegant (and hopefully efficient) way to do this?

Thanks for any help,

Jack

Comment: how do you get/receive this financial data?

Comment: @MaxU: Iirc, pandas has a module to pull stock data

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thank you i know. If OP uses `pandas_datareader` there is a much more elegant solution... ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm drawing data locally from csv files.

Comment: Do you have all the DataFrames in a list? and are the names of the stocks in a list too? (Storing the names of the stocks in variable names is [problematic](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).)

Comment: Yes they are in a dictionary as `{'AAPL' : df_AAPL, 'CSCO' : df_CSCO ...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [*concatenate* a dict of DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), `dfs`, into a single DataFrame using

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

`df` will use the dict keys as a MultiIndex level.

---

For example,

```
In [85]: dfs = {'AAPL': df_asset, 'CSCO': df_asset}

In [86]: df = pd.concat(dfs); df
Out[86]: 
            Open      High       Low     Close
AAPL 0  0.100276  0.769425  0.060993  0.831183
     1  0.251792  0.336571  0.976984  0.237506
     2  0.611914  0.029576  0.329525  0.203794
     3  0.527770  0.723468  0.887708  0.231006
     4  0.965805  0.508156  0.260214  0.063260
CSCO 0  0.100276  0.769425  0.060993  0.831183
     1  0.251792  0.336571  0.976984  0.237506
     2  0.611914  0.029576  0.329525  0.203794
     3  0.527770  0.723468  0.887708  0.231006
     4  0.965805  0.508156  0.260214  0.063260
```

---

To get the index levels in the order that you posted in your question, use [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) followed by [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
In [112]: df.swaplevel().sort_index()
Out[112]: 
            Open      High       Low     Close
0 AAPL  0.100276  0.769425  0.060993  0.831183
  CSCO  0.100276  0.769425  0.060993  0.831183
1 AAPL  0.251792  0.336571  0.976984  0.237506
  CSCO  0.251792  0.336571  0.976984  0.237506
2 AAPL  0.611914  0.029576  0.329525  0.203794
  CSCO  0.611914  0.029576  0.329525  0.203794
3 AAPL  0.527770  0.723468  0.887708  0.231006
  CSCO  0.527770  0.723468  0.887708  0.231006
4 AAPL  0.965805  0.508156  0.260214  0.063260
  CSCO  0.965805  0.508156  0.260214  0.063260
```

Comment: I think OP also wanted to swap index levels... : `df = pd.concat(dfs); df = df.set_index(df.index.swaplevel())`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It looks great. What if I wanted to get the index `0, 1, 2, 3, ...` as the "left index" and the stocks as the "right index"? Like in `df` in my question.

Comment: Ah, thanks MaxU. You answered my question before I had asked it!

Comment: @MaxU: Yes, thanks. Somewhere along the way (0.18.1?) `swaplevel` was raised to a [DataFrame method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html).