# How to compute hash of all the columns in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

`df.apply` is a method that can apply a certain function to all the columns in a dataframe, or the required columns. However, my aim is to compute the hash of a string: this string is the concatenation of all the values in a row corresponding to all the columns. My current code is returning `NaN`.

The current code is:

```
df["row_hash"] = df["row_hash"].apply(self.hash_string)
```

The function `self.hash_string` is:

```
def hash_string(self, value):
        return (sha1(str(value).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

Yes, it would be easier to merge all columns of Pandas dataframe but [current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290687/merging-all-columns-of-pandas-dataframes) couldn't help me either.

The file that I am reading is(the first 10 rows):

```
16012,16013,16014,16015,16016,16017,16018,16019,16020,16021,16022
16013,16014,16015,16016,16017,16018,16019,16020,16021,16022,16023
16014,16015,16016,16017,16018,16019,16020,16021,16022,16023,16024
16015,16016,16017,16018,16019,16020,16021,16022,16023,16024,16025
16016,16017,16018,16019,16020,16021,16022,16023,16024,16025,16026
```

The col names are: `col_test_1, col_test_2, .... , col_test_11`

Comment: Could you add some sample input?

Comment: Just to clarify, the non-hashed value of the first row should be something like `160121601316014...`?

Comment: @AndrewF Yes! It is the concatenation of the values of all columns in the same order as in the file and then the hash of that concatenated string.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new column, which is concatenation of all others:

```
df['new'] = df.astype(str).values.sum(axis=1)
```

And then apply your hash function on it

```
df["row_hash"] = df["new"].apply(self.hash_string)
```

or this one-row should work:

```
df["row_hash"] = df.astype(str).values.sum(axis=1).apply(hash_string)
```

However, not sure if you need a separate function here, so:

```
 df["row_hash"] = df.astype(str).values.sum(axis=1).apply(lambda x: sha1(str(x).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply` twice, first on the row elements then on the result:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1).apply(self.hash_string)
```

*Sidenote*: I don't understand why you are defining hash_string as an instance method (instead of a plain function), since it doesn't use the `self` argument. In case you have problems can just pass it as function:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1).apply(lambda value: sha1(str(value).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

Comment: Keeping a single source of truth is my priority so that if one day I change the hashing algorithm to say, md5, it will be a change in one place and not in multiple operations. :)